# Specify search_path for Postgres connection in Connection URL

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there anyway in SQLAlchemy to specify what `search_path` should be set when using the DB URL to specify the connection details when connecting to a postgres DB?

For reference, [the Django library `dj-database-url` supports this](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url/blob/99b5b7c697536314f691f66e0e2ef59b70edec7e/dj_database_url.py#L127) and [usage example](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url/blob/99b5b7c697536314f691f66e0e2ef59b70edec7e/test_dj_database_url.py#L47).

Answer (score 0):

you can specify `currentSchema` in connection string to replace default

Comment: Citation? I don't see the string in the source: https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=currentSchema